# Reading excel file in Laravel

Tags: php, excel, laravel, laravel-5, maatwebsite-excel

I'm using [Maatwebsite](http://www.maatwebsite.nl/laravel-excel/docs)'s library for reading and creating excel file. The creating was easy and somehow intuitive, but when it comes to reading one, I simply can't figure it out.

This is how my excel file looks like:
[image]

I figured out how to loop through rows, but what confused me that $row in my example is really type of string, so I can't do $row->something;

In my controller I want to read it like this:

```
 Excel::load('storage\\exports\\'. $fName, function($reader) {
    $reader->each(function($sheet) {
        Log::warning("sheet happens");

        // Loop through rows            
        $sheet->each(function($row) {
            Log::warning($row);
        });

    });
});
```

This gives me output

```
[2016-01-28 06:42:05] local.WARNING: sheet happens  
[2016-01-28 06:42:05] local.WARNING:   
[2016-01-28 06:42:05] local.WARNING:   
[2016-01-28 06:42:05] local.WARNING:   
[2016-01-28 06:42:05] local.WARNING:   
[2016-01-28 06:42:05] local.WARNING:   
[2016-01-28 06:42:05] local.WARNING:   
[2016-01-28 06:42:05] local.WARNING: sheet happens  
[2016-01-28 06:42:05] local.WARNING: ocjena  
[2016-01-28 06:42:05] local.WARNING: Kolokvijum 1 (%)  
[2016-01-28 06:42:05] local.WARNING: Kolokvijum 2  
[2016-01-28 06:42:05] local.WARNING: Kolokvijum 2 (%)  
[2016-01-28 06:42:05] local.WARNING: Završni ispit (%)  
[2016-01-28 06:42:05] local.WARNING: Završni ispit
```

It confused me that output is not in the right order.

It confused me that my row is type of string. Why?

Is it possible to access specific cells like we do in matrix: $table[$row][$column]; ?

If you can't answer my question I would really apreciate if you have any piece of working code since there is not very much docs online.

EDIT: I found out that I have multiple words at my headers, so somehow it all gets mixed up.

EDIT: Cause there is not much docs online I feel like I should share what solved it.

The solution code:

```
$rows = Excel::load('storage\\exports\\'. $fName)->get();
Log::warning($rows);
```

Prints out:

```
[{"ime_studenta":"andrej","broj_indeksa":4,"kolokvijum_1":4,"kolokvijum_2":4,"zavrsni_ispit":44,"ukupno":4,"ocjena":4},{"ime_studenta":"as","broj_indeksa":342,"kolokvijum_1":123,"kolokvijum_2":57,"zavrsni_ispit":56,"ukupno":5656,"ocjena":56}]
```

Comment: I couldn't get the Laravel Facade working for that.  I ended up using PHPExcel directly.  It's pretty easy to use and has additional functionality that I couldn't get working in Maatwebsite.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe this is useful for you

```
$rows = Excel::load('storage\\exports\\'. $fName)->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//Using PHPExcel IOFactory

public function index() 
{
        $inputFileName = 'example.xlsx';

        $spreadsheet = IOFactory::load($inputFileName);
        $sheetData = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null, true, true, true);

        //dd($sheetData);

        foreach ($sheetData as $rows=>$k) {
                $num = $rows;
            foreach ($k as $key=>$value) {
                $excel = new Excel;
                $excel->cell_number = $num;
                $excel->cell_letter = $key;
                $excel->cell_value = $value;   
                $excel->save(); 
            }
        }

        return view('excel', compact('sheetData'));
}
```